# i want import my file in python but can't import

Tags: python, django, import, path

First, I typed `from awsdjp.boardapp.views import *` but error occurred.

Full Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\awsdjp\awsdjp\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('boardapp/',include('boardapp.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProj\awsdjp\boardapp\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from awsdjp.boardapp.views import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsdjp.boardapp'
```

I was googling about this issue .

Next, I typed

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\djangoProj\\")
```

That path is my directory's absolute path

And run but don't work ....

`from awsdjp.boardapp.views import *` part is not recognized.

[image]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: in which file did you use it ? Maybe you should use `from boardapp.views import *` or even `from views import *` - all depends on in which file you use it.

Comment: Python's autocomplete system recognizes it from awsdjp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `import *`, make sure that all the modules are imported in your `boardapp/__init__.py`

e.g.:

```py
# boardapp/__init__.py
from . import admin
from . import apps
from . import models
from . import tests
from . import urls
from . import views
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import from awsdjp\boardapp\urls.py, which is in the same folder as the views.py file, you can just use relative import like this:

```
from .views import *
```